# Python api post request

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I want to convert this code to use python3 and use python-requests.
Please help me

```
import unirest
response = unirest.post("https://api.pixhost.to/images",
headers={
"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8",
"Accept": "application/json"
},
params={
"img": open("image.jpg", mode="r"),
"content_type": "0",
"max_th_size": "420"
}
)
```

for reference here is the docs
https://pixhost.to/api/index.html?python#images

Comment: import requests
params={
"img":open("image.jpg", 'rb'),
"content_type": "0",
"max_th_size": "420"
}
headers={
"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8",
"Accept": "application/json"
}

 url = "https://api.pixhost.to/images"
response = requests.post(url,data=params,headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
headers={"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8","Accept":"application/json"}
params={"img": open("image.jpg", mode="r"),"content_type": "0","max_th_size": "420"}
response = requests.post("https://api.pixhost.to/images", headers=headers, data=params)
```